# Forecasting Fortnightly data using OLS

Tags: python, time-series, regression

### I have bimonthly data of the customer sales and the data looks like

```
Sales_date  Cigarette_sales
10/15/2015   2,783 
11/1/2015    385 
11/15/2015   536 
12/1/2015    768 
12/15/2015   413 
1/1/2016     182 
1/15/2016    529 
2/1/2016     398 
2/15/2016    22 
3/1/2016     65 
3/15/2016    603 
4/1/2016     759 
4/15/2016    64 
5/1/2016     391 
5/15/2016    669 
6/1/2016     833 
6/15/2016    516 
7/1/2016     480 
7/15/2016    260 
8/1/2016     252 
8/15/2016    689 
9/1/2016     119 
9/15/2016    812 
10/1/2016    275 
10/15/2016   425 
11/1/2016    132 
11/15/2016   26 
12/1/2016    170 
12/15/2016   321 
1/1/2017     349 
1/15/2017    102 
2/1/2017     155 
2/15/2017    117 
3/1/2017     99 
3/15/2017    812 
4/1/2017     441 
4/15/2017    51 
5/1/2017     210 
5/15/2017    625 
6/1/2017     42 
6/15/2017    333 
7/1/2017     460 
7/15/2017    1,580 
8/1/2017     632 
8/15/2017    441 
9/1/2017     80 
9/15/2017    723 
10/1/2017    209 
10/15/2017   377 
11/1/2017    493 
11/15/2017   475 
12/1/2017    252 
12/15/2017   735
```

Since for linear regressions on time series data, we need a numeric indicator
for time period so I have created a days variable for DatetimeIndex which is simply a counter from 0 on my training dataset

train['days'] = range(len(train))

```
10/15/2015   2,783  0
11/1/2015    385    1
11/15/2015   536    2
12/1/2015    768    3
12/15/2015   413    4
1/1/2016     182    5
1/15/2016    529    6
2/1/2016     398    7
2/15/2016    22     8
3/1/2016     65     9
3/15/2016    603    10
4/1/2016     759    11
4/15/2016    64     12
5/1/2016     391    13
5/15/2016    669    14
6/1/2016     833    15
6/15/2016    516    16
7/1/2016     480    17
7/15/2016    260    18
8/1/2016     252    19
8/15/2016    689    20
9/1/2016     119    21
9/15/2016    812    22
10/1/2016    275    23
10/15/2016   425    24
11/1/2016    132    25
11/15/2016   26     26
12/1/2016    170    27
12/15/2016   321    28
1/1/2017     349    29
1/15/2017    102    30
2/1/2017     155    31
2/15/2017    117    32
3/1/2017     99     33
3/15/2017    812    34
4/1/2017     441    35
4/15/2017    51     36
5/1/2017     210    37
5/15/2017    625    38
6/1/2017     42     39
6/15/2017    333    40
7/1/2017     460    41
7/15/2017    1,580  42
8/1/2017     632    43
8/15/2017    441    44
9/1/2017     80     45
9/15/2017    723    46
10/1/2017    209    47
10/15/2017   377    48
11/1/2017    493    49
11/15/2017   475    50
12/1/2017    252    51
12/15/2017   735    52
```

when I try to fit the OLS regression on the cigarette sales on days

sales_lm4 = smf.ols(cigarette_sales ~ days', data=salesdata).fit()

this is my summary

Dep. Variable:  cigarette_sales     R-squared:  0.001
Model:  OLS Adj. R-squared: -0.019
Method: Least Squares   F-statistic:    0.03564
Date:   Fri, 29 Jun 2018    Prob (F-statistic): 0.851
Time:   8:51:28 Log-Likelihood: -73.31
No. Observations:   52  AIC:    150.6
Df Residuals:   50  BIC:    154.5
Df Model:   1
Covariance Type:    nonrobust
coef    std err t   P>|t|   [0.025  0.975]
Intercept   19.3901 0.284   68.187  0   18.819  19.961
days    0.0018  0.009   0.189   0.851   -0.017  0.021
Omnibus:    8.573   Durbin-Watson:  1.795
Prob(Omnibus):  0.014   Jarque-Bera (JB):   8.209
Skew:   -0.959  Prob(JB):   0.0165
Kurtosis:   3.331   Cond. No.   61.8

### Even when I take the log of the sales data there is not much change in the summary statistics

sales_lm4 = smf.ols(log_cigarette_sales ~ days', data=salesdata).fit()

Dep. Variable:
log_cigarette_sales
R-squared:
0.002

Model:
OLS
Adj. R-squared:
-0.017

Method:
Least Squares
F-statistic:
0.1134

Date:
Tue, 03 Jul 2018
Prob (F-statistic):
0.738

Time:
09:29:19
Log-Likelihood:
-76.756

No. Observations:
53
AIC:
157.5

Df Residuals:
51
BIC:
161.5

Df Model:
1

Covariance Type:
nonrobust

coef

std err

t

P>|t|

[0.025

0.975]

Intercept
19.5629 0.284 68.799 0.000 18.992 20.134

days
-0.0032 0.009 -0.337 0.738 -0.022 0.016

Omnibus:
6.854
Durbin-Watson:
1.701

Prob(Omnibus):
0.032
Jarque-Bera (JB):
5.975

Skew:
-0.789
Prob(JB):
0.0504

Kurtosis:
3.462
Cond. No.
59.5

### how can I use more modify this series to produce a good model where I have a good r square and adjusted r square values. What is that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your data looks quite random. Your autocorrelation values are also very low. You can try methods like exponential smoothing but without additional variables that would explain this variance I don't think it can be improved much.

Comment: I will try to do exponential smoothening , but before that I want to ask is changing the date time index to the days variable the right thing to do?  Is there any other day to creating the day variables?

Comment: Yes the general approach in time series regression is to assign successive numbers for regularly spaced periods. In addition to that you can add dummy variables to model seasonality but your data doesn't exhibit any seasonal effect.

Comment: yes, I have checked for seasonality but this series is quite stationary. There is a little trend and I tried doing the differencing but the r square on the differencing sales is much less than the one displayed here.

Comment: is there any other way to correct this

Answer (score 2):

Before anything, make a plot. It is quite obvious on it that 10/15/2015 and 7/15/2017 are outliers. Remove them form the training set.

The data still fluctuates a lot. You have two ways of getting rid of the fluctuation: (a) make a moving average, (b) look at the cumulative data. For the first, if you do not average on a full a seasonal cycle, you introduce a bias (which can be removed afterwards but requires some extra computation). So for the first pass, I prefer to keep the data as raw as possible.

Taking cumulative data [`y(t) = x(t)+y(t-1)`] makes the fluctuation vanishes (there is not magic, the fluctuation is an order of magnitude lower than the trend). The graph here is almost linear, indicating a stable (constant) customer sale. A linear regression tells you the sloop is 369.48, in other words the sales is about 369.48 per 15 days.

You can then compute the residual `e(t)=x(t)-369.48`, and look for seasonality in there. I do not see any, but be sure by making an autocorrelation.

So your best forecast is 369.48.

[image]

Comment: @AlainD..can you please explain a little more on when you say "the fluctuation is an order of magnitude lower than the trend"\

Comment: @AlainD-- for x=1, x=1 385(1)=1(1)+385(1-1), for t=2, x=2 536(2)=2(2)+536(2-1)...is this right of rthe cumulative equation?

Comment: If the raw series is (385, 536, 768, 413, 182,...) then the cumulative is (385, 921, 1689, 2102, 2284,...), because 385+536=921, 921+768=1689, etc... It's magic to remove fluctuation. The price is that the trend is a bit more difficult to interpret.